# TableHead of mui doesn't take full width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
  return (
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableCell></TableCell>
        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
      </TableHead>
    </Table>
  );
```

which gives me this:

[image]

How can i remove that surrounded small space

Comment: Difficult to say without seing the code. Also, which space are you talking about? Container space or some wrapper?

Comment: hey, i'm talking about the space that's surrounded by a red line, the vertical grey rectangle just before the green element

Comment: What does the inspector say is causing that space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the first cell of the table head, you'll see that its css class contains:
`box-shadow: inset 8px 0 0 #fff;`

So what you have to do is to override it by doing:

```
import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  thead: {
    '& th:first-child': { borderRadius: '0', boxShadow: 'none', paddingLeft: '30px' },
    '& th:last-child': { borderRadius: '0', boxShadow: 'none', paddingRight: '30px' },
  },
}));

const classes = useStyles();
```

And then passing the `classes` variable to `TableHead`:

```
<TableHead classes={{ root: classes.thead }}>
    // [...]
</TableHead>
```